# Is it possible to use CSS nested rules without installing anything on the server?

Tags: css, nested, sass, less

LESS and SASS allow us to use CSS nested rules; however, they require us to install their components on the web servers.

Is it possible to use similar feature without installing anything on the server? Maybe by using JavaScript, jQuery, etc. I could achieve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 7):

Just like people who minimize javascript files as part of deployment (without installing anything on the server), you can process LESS files into regular CSS files as part of your deployment or packaging step.  The tools can run on a developer's computer and be used once at deployment time and not have to ever install any executables on the server.

I'm sure there are many LESS compiler options, but here are a couple:

- [LESS CSS on Windows](http://digitalpbk.com/less-css/less-css-compiler-windows-lesscexe)
- [dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it doesn't need to be converted on the server, it can be converted on the developer's machine.

Comment: And you don't have to needlessly send over an extra JS file and client-side processing

Comment: @jfriend00: I am trying to use LESS with the [HTML5 Biolerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). I am trying to use this for a small project... do I still need to compile LESS on my local machine?

Comment: I don't know HTML5 Boilerplate.  You need to make sure that a visitor's browser gets generic CSS, not LESS.  If the HTML5 Boilerplate tools don't do that for you, then you will need to compile LESS yourself. It should be easy for you to look at the deployment files and see if they are still LESS or if they have been converted to regular CSS.

Comment: @Fawadafr it'll be best for performance to compile it on the dev machine, and there are now decent options for doing so on Windows (this didn't used to be true) so that's the best way.  If you want to just test it out then the client-side javascript solution should also work.

Comment: @Davy8 Understood. This is my first time trying to use LESS... I do use Windows7 and IIS for the design purposes. So, basically I need to create a LESS file to write all my nested rules then compile it using on of the Windows compilers and then use it on the browser... did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Fawadafr Yes that's correct.  And your "nested rules" must match the LESS syntax as described on their site.  If you're just playing around trying to get it to work, then the javascript method might be easier to get started, but for deploying seriously it should be pre-compiled.

Answer (score 4):

Less can run in a strictly client-side mode using JavaScript. Just include `less.js` in your page.

[image]

http://lesscss.org/#guide

Comment: Yes, I included the LESS style and less.js in the page header and added my CSS simple nested rule in the CSS file which is included in the HTML file but don't see the style on the browser... I did follow the instruction available on LESS website.

Comment: Did you set the correct `rel` attribute on the `<link>`? It should be `rel="stylesheet/less"`. Are you sure the browser isn't receiving a 404 on either file?

Comment: @Fawadafr did you "Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script."?

Comment: @Fawadafr You said "added my CSS simple nested rule in the CSS file" but if it's LESS syntax it should go in the LESS file, not as CSS file.

Comment: @Davy8 yes, I have the stylesheet before the script. So, my nested stylesheet should go in the LESS file not the .CSS file? How can I create a LESS file? Thank you

Comment: @Fawadafr Nested rules can't go in a CSS file, because it's not valid CSS.  Nesting is not allowed in CSS, so you're actually writing a different language that's similar to CSS, but is not CSS.  The site explained exactly how to include it, so if both files exist (the less.js file and the styles.less file that you created) and you link to them exactly as described under the "Client side usage" section lesscss.org then it should work.  Using this method, you don't have a CSS file, the CSS is *created* by the javascript, it doesn't exist until the page loads.

Comment: @Davy8 Thanks for your help. I added some LESS styles in the styles.less file and then compiled it using the Less Compiler. Then, styles.css was generated by the compiler. Do I need to go back to the HTML page and add a new reference link to the newly created stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

in short, yes, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grouping_nesting.asp.

Not quite the SASS syntax but accomplishes the same effect.
To further the answer Javascript can be used to apply the nested CSS dynamically.